# Local repository wont get updated, when composer update, why?

Tags: php, composer-php

My 3rd party components:

```
{
  "name": "3rd/test,
  "type": "vcs",
  "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

the project that want to use it:

```
{
  "name": "test/test",
  "type": "project",
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "/path/of/3rd/library",
      "options": {
        "symlink": false
      }
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "3rd/test": "*",
    "php": ">=8.1",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "ext-gd": "*",
    "ext-zlib": "*",
    "ext-mysqli": "*",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-bcmath": "*",
    "ext-zip": "*",
    "ext-pdo": "*",
    "ext-sqlite3": "*"
  }
}
```

first it will copy the 3rd party library to vendor/ directory, so far so good. But when I make a modification in the 3rd library and use composer update, it wont update that file! Why?

Comment: Did you increase the version number of the 3rd party library? That's how composer knows whether to pick up the changes.

Comment: Composer doesn't verify file diffs, it compares versions and if package directory exists in vendor. Why don't you use symlink? It would resolve the issue.

Comment: because its Windows and there is no symlinks

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you should specify `@dev`.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links

Also, if you copy/pasted your 3rd/pary composer.json, then your missing a " sign, making it invalid JSON.